# Cheerio don't work with tag <td>

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
var $ = cheerio.load('<td>check text</td>');
console.log($('td').text());
```

No results for TD and TR. How i can get text content from TD and TR without using classes or id (only ) ?

Comment: That looks like a bug to me. Maybe you should report it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well `td` element has no significance without `table` element as parent. Following snippet would work as expected.

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
var $ = cheerio.load('<table><tr><td>check text</td></tr></table>');
console.log($('td').text());
```